# Inserting .csv to sqllite3 with "expected 5 columns but found 1" problem

Tags: sqlite

So I am trying to insert the .csv to sqllite but as I mentioned `"expected 5 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL"` appeares.

I tried to use some different code lines which I found here and there like

```
"""sqlite3 urunler.db -separator ',' '.import /sticin.csv users'"""
```

But I couldn't solve the problem.

```
"""sqlite3 urunler.db -separator ',' '.import /sticin.csv users'"""
```

This is my first time dealing with .csv and sqlite so If you could guiede me with a solution that works, it would be perfect.

Comment: Post data sample here.

Comment: first three strings are like this                                  
 1."Musteri Adı ;Urun No. ; Kalip No. ;Urun Adi ; Kalip Durumu "                                                                   2."A ; 102 ; ; Flange; Dovuluyor"                              
3."A ; 103 ; ; GrundKorper; Hazir"

Comment: So why are you using the separator ',' when your data file has the separator ';'?

Comment: Because the sqlite can not get the datas seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `-separator` is to separate fields during printing the result, the internal sqlite command `.separator` is also to choose a separator for importing files. Choose the import separator and then import the file.

```
sqlite3 urunler.db ".separator ';'" ".import sticin.csv users"

sqlite> select * from users;
Musteri Adı |Urun No. | Kalip No. |Urun Adi | Kalip Durumu
A | 102 | | Flange| Dovuluyor
A | 103 | | GrundKorper| Hazir
```